# How to create dynamic dropdown list and change event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

How can I create 2 dropdown lists dynamically and change event, using jQuery?

[image]

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    var counter = 0;
    $("button").click(function() {
        $("#div2").append("<select id='pincode' class='pincode' name='my_select_name'><option value='1'>1</option><option value='2'>2</option></select> <select id='pincode1' name='my_select_name1' class='pincode1'><option value='1'>1</option><option value='2'>2</option></select><br/>")
    });

    $(document).on("click", ".pincode", function(){
        $('.pincode1').empty(); // alert($(this).text());
    });
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">
    <div id="div2"></div>
</div>
<button>generate new element</button>
```

**EDIT:** I added div and common class name for doing this task.

Comment: Please share some code, so that we can help you out.

Comment: Please include the code that you've tried, as inline text, and describe which part you're having a problem with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/woghjyd5/

```js
var counter = 0;

$("button").click(function() {
    $("#div2").append("<select class='pincode' name='my_select_name'><option value='1'>1</option><option value='2'>2</option></select> <select name='my_select_name1' class='pincode1'><option value='1'>1</option><option value='2'>2</option></select><br/>")
});



$(document).on("click", ".pincode", function(){
  $($(this).next()).empty();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">
<div id="div2"></div>
</div>
<button>generate new element</button>
```

I guess this is what you are looking for.

Comment: can we call ajax call in that event

Comment: How to write ajax call with current id and bind data in next dropdownlist .

Comment: Here you go with an example https://jsfiddle.net/woghjyd5/1/   .. Here is the documentation for ajax call. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: @shilditya thanks your help . I got exactly solution I want only one change how to find next element and bind that data in that element.

Comment: $($(this).next()); This code will help you to get the next element whatever you have selected..

Comment: @shilditya If don't mind can give some piece of code . Bcoz i am fresher in jquery plz

Comment: @LingrajGowda.. It's present in the jsfiddle next(); Here is the documentation https://api.jquery.com/next/

Comment: With we can do bind the data in what we are getting in ajax success success: function(data) {
$.each(data.d, function(key, value) {
$("#ddlCountry").append($("<option></option>").val(value.CountryId).html(value.CountryName));
});  how we can do on this code